# Why does snow disappear without melting?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, ice, phase-diagram

During very cold weather, snow often gradually disappear without melting.

Comment: A little melting and soaking into the ground happens a lot also. And snow can just settle and compact without melting, but giving the appearance of disappearing without really disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At certain conditions of low temperature and low humidity, snow changes directly to water vapour by sublimation, without going through the liquid phase.

Comment: This process doesn't require certain conditions; it happens under all conditions under exactly 100% RH. However, it may predominate (in terms of snow disappearance) only under certain conditions.

Answer (score 4):

It’s called sublimation. Sublimation for snow is like evaporation is for water: occasionally a surface molecule with have enough thermal energy to escape into the air. It goes faster if the humidity is lower and the temperature is higher, but it happens at some rate always.

Comment: Is this really a larger contribution than snow that melts then evaporates? Small quantities of liquid water that evaporate quickly would make it appear that the snow isn't melting unless you look closely, and this seems more likely in mass than sublimation

Comment: The question says “very cold weather”, when melting should not be happening.

Answer (score 2):

If the air (and ground) temperature is low enough such that the snow stays frozen, then the sun will cause evaporation from the surface. This is sublimation because the snow is going directly from solid to gas. Drier air will speed this up because there are that many fewer water molecules in the air to go back to the snow.

However, if the air or ground temperature is not low enough to keep the snow frozen, then the snow will melt before it can evaporate.

Air and ground temperature are the primary factors that determine whether the snow melts or stays frozen as it evaporates. Low humidity is also a factor that can speed the evaporation up.